# UTC date time returned by server using PHP is different than actual UTC date time

Tags: php, timezone, timezone-offset

My server has timezone set to UTC. so when I do `echo date_default_timezone_get ();` I get `UTC`.

But when I do `echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");` the datetime I get is around 33-34 mins 
late than actual UTC date time. I checked if there was time offset by doing `echo date('Z');` but that returns 0 as well. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you considered the time on that server may simply be wrong (and not automatically set)?

Comment: Please run `date` in a shell and check if the date is correct or not. If not, I recommend installing and configuring ntp on the machine.